# Search filters and sorting filters

Tags: java, android

In my Android application, I have two types of filters: search filters and sorting filters.

I need to read filters from view, display filter on view, and save them into and from memory. I should include these needed features into one class to help myself add new filters in the future. I also need to divide filters by their type.

Filters in my app represented via:

- `Comparator<T>` interface from Java SDK (for sorting filters)
- `SearchCriterion<T>` interface (for search filters)

  ```
  public interface SearchCriterion<T> {
      boolean meetCriterion(T obj);
  }
  ```

To do something needed I wrote an `interface`:

```
public interface Filter {
    void readFrom(View view);
    void displayOn(View view);
    void restoreFrom(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences);
    void saveInto(SharedPreferences.Editor editor);
    void includeInIfNeed(Filters filters);
}
```

Example of `Filter` subclass:

```
class SearchFilterByDiscountType implements Filter {

    private static class KeysOfDiscountTypes {
        public static final String BONUS = getClassName() + "Bonus";
        public static final String DISCOUNT = getClassName() + "Discount";
        public static final String CASH_BACK = getClassName() + "Cash Back";
    }

    private static String getClassName() {
        return SearchFilterDiscountType.class.getSimpleName();
    }

    private static final boolean DEFAULT_BONUS = true;
    private static final boolean DEFAULT_DISCOUNT = true;
    private static final boolean DEFAULT_CASH_BACK = true;

    private boolean bonus;
    private boolean discount;
    private boolean cashBack;

    public SearchFilterDiscountType() {
        bonus = DEFAULT_BONUS;
        discount = DEFAULT_DISCOUNT;
        cashBack = DEFAULT_CASH_BACK;
    }

    @Override
    public void readFrom(View view) {
        bonus = findCheckBox(view, R.id.bonusCheckBox).isChecked();
        discount = findCheckBox(view, R.id.discountCheckBox).isChecked();
        cashBack = findCheckBox(view, R.id.cashBackCheckBox).isChecked();
    }

    @Override
    public void displayOn(View view) {
        findCheckBox(view, R.id.bonusCheckBox).setChecked(bonus);
        findCheckBox(view, R.id.discountCheckBox).setChecked(discount);
        findCheckBox(view, R.id.cashBackCheckBox).setChecked(cashBack);
    }

    private CheckBox findCheckBox(View view, int idOfCheckBox) {
        return (CheckBox) view.findViewById(idOfCheckBox);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreFrom(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
        bonus = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KeysOfDiscountTypes.BONUS, DEFAULT_BONUS);
        discount = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KeysOfDiscountTypes.DISCOUNT, DEFAULT_DISCOUNT);
        cashBack = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KeysOfDiscountTypes.CASH_BACK, DEFAULT_CASH_BACK);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveInto(SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
        editor.putBoolean(KeysOfDiscountTypes.BONUS, bonus);
        editor.putBoolean(KeysOfDiscountTypes.DISCOUNT, discount);
        editor.putBoolean(KeysOfDiscountTypes.CASH_BACK, cashBack);
    }

    @Override
    public void includeInIfNeed(Filters filters) {
        filters.add(new DiscountTypeSearchCriterion(bonus, discount, cashBack));
    }
}
```

To divide filters by their type I wrote this class:

```
public class Filters implements Serializable {
    public final List<SearchableListing.SearchCriterion<PartnerPoint>> searchCriteria;
    public final List<Comparator<PartnerPoint>> comparators;

    public static Filters from(List<Filter> filters) {
        Filters result = new Filters();
        for (Filter filter : filters) {
            filter.includeInIfNeed(result);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Filters() {
        searchCriteria = new ArrayList<SearchableListing.SearchCriterion<PartnerPoint>>();
        comparators = new ArrayList<Comparator<PartnerPoint>>();
    }

    public void add(SearchableListing.SearchCriterion<PartnerPoint> searchCriterion) {
        searchCriteria.add(searchCriterion);
    }

    public void add(Comparator<PartnerPoint> comparator) {
        comparators.add(comparator);
    }

    public void add(Filters other) {
        searchCriteria.addAll(other.searchCriteria);
        comparators.addAll(other.comparators);
    }
}
```

But in my opinion, `Filter` and `Filters` are confusing names for these very different interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have presented similar code to this before, and while some of the recommendations I had have been implemented, others have not... ;-) This is fine, presumably you have your reasons, but the one that sticks out is the `public void includeInIfNeed(Filters filters)` method, which is redundant....

As for naming, I have a few recommendations:

- `Filter` is a fine name for it. No need to change.
- `SearchFilterByDiscountType` does not search, it is used to search. I use the convention that a specialization of a class/implementation should (normally) use the base class as a suffix. So, here the `Filter` should go to the end, and become `DiscountTypeFilter`. This is somewhat standard, think of `List`, `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc.
- `Filters` is not a completely bad name, I agree it could be better, but if this was 'production' code I probably would not change it because the mess in the change logs would not be worth it. On the other hand, it is simple enough to change now, and I have a number of suffixes I use.... `Set`, `List`, `Array`, `Chain`, `Pack`, `Group` and some others I forget right now. I use the suffix that most closely represents the structure and data access mechanism of the data in the collection. In this case, I would probably use `FilterChain`.

There are two other suggestions I have:

- `Filters` is not actually Serializable, so why is it declared to be?
- It woul dbe really convenient if the `Filters` (`FilterChain`?) class also implements the `Filter` interface which would allow you to apply filters in a batched fashion.